# How to build ROS `.deb` packages by myself?

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, python3, ubuntu, ubuntu-bionic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

In my project, we are currently using ROS Melodic (`apt install` from the official Ubuntu Package Server) on Ubuntu 18.04. By default, Melodic was built for Python 2. However,

- We have migrated from Python 2 to 3 since the official support for Python 2 has ended.
- We haven't decided to migrate our product to Ubuntu 20.04 (Focal Fossa) which ROS Noetic is targeted at.

Therefore, I'm helping the team to bring Python 3 to ROS on Ubuntu 18.04. I'm following the ["Transitioning to Python 3"](http://wiki.ros.org/UsingPython3) to build the Melodic source on 18.04. In addition, because my team has built our internal Debian package server, I'm thinking about publishing the ROS packages I'm building as `.deb` packages so other developers can simply `apt install` from our package server, without having to build by themselves.

I've learned that ROS build farm can publish `.deb` packages so I guess the Debian files (e.g., `changelog`, `control`, `rules`) may be available somewhere that I can directly reuse. **Could someone tell me where they are or how they are currently generated?**

But I'm also open to other solutions. The main goal I want to achieve is to "have a ROS distribution with full Python 3 support that can be installed on Ubuntu 18.04", so I'm also thinking about other possibilities:

1. Install Noetic on 18.04 using the official Ubuntu Package Server. I tried but this failed (surely) because Noetic requires many other packages that are built for 20.04 but not 18.04.
2. Backport Noetic onto 18.04. But I think I still want to figure out how to publish them as `.deb` packages on our internal package server.

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/356310/how-to-build-ros-%60.deb%60-packages-by-myself?/) by [yaobin](https://answers.ros.org/users/56085/yaobin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2020-07-02

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Solrac3589](https://answers.ros.org/users/31684/solrac3589/) on 2020-07-03**:
What about using a docker image of noetic? you should be able to work with noetic in ubuntu 18.04

**Comment by [yaobin](https://answers.ros.org/users/56085/yaobin/) on 2020-07-06**:
@solrac3589: That sounds like an appealing idea. Thanks! I'll give a try when possible. But, if possible, I still hope to learn where all the Debian materials are stored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> Could someone tell me where they are or how they are currently generated?

They're located in the `debian` folder in tags on the release repos. These tags are generated by a tool called [bloom](http://wiki.ros.org/bloom). Here's an example for the `1.4.1` release of `ros-melodic-viz`: https://github.com/ros-gbp/metapackages-release/tree/debian/ros-melodic-viz_1.4.1-0_bionic/debian

> But I'm also open to other solutions. The main goal I want to achieve is to "have a ROS distribution with full Python 3 support that can be installed on Ubuntu 18.04", so I'm also thinking about other possibilities:

I think you could run your own instances of the ROS buildfarm: https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/ros_buildfarm with a caveat that there are many pieces to it. One piece is maintianing a [`distribution.yaml` with the release platform being `bionic`](https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/blob/5279575c3da4181de9fe1e9a2b4b0e5e5a15c7d2/noetic/distribution.yaml#L6-L11) and releases for all of your dependencies that have been forked.

> Backport Noetic onto 18.04. But I think I still want to figure out how to publish them as `.deb` packages on our internal package server.

There were a lot of changes in Noetic to get things working smoothly in Python 3, so I would expect a lot of backporting.  That said the Arch linux users have used `Melodic` for a while with Python 3, so you may find useful info there: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/ROS .

---

Originally posted by [sloretz](https://answers.ros.org/users/23470/sloretz/) with karma: 3061 on 2020-07-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [yaobin](https://answers.ros.org/users/56085/yaobin/) on 2020-07-12**:
Thank you for all the information!